# Entity Framework Code first making a column non-nullable

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using EF code first for my project. I have following code in my DataModel

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]        
public DateTime? PasswordDate { get; set; }
```

To make this non-nullable I removed '?' and ran Add-Migration command from Package manager console. following migration file was generated.

```
  public partial class PasswordDate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.CertificateInfoes", "PasswordDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.CertificateInfoes", "PasswordDate", c => c.DateTime());
    }
}
```

But when I run Update-Database command:

```
Update-Database -SourceMigration 201309020721215_PasswordDate
```

I get following error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PasswordDate', table ''; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Kindly suggest the solutions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because you allowed `NULL` values in that column, then tried to make it non-nullable. It will subsequently try to migrate your existing data into that newly non-nullable column, which will break because you already have `NULL` values in there.

Two solutions:

1) Change it back to nullable 
2) Give it a default value for items that don't have a value.

Comment: I can not change it back to nullable. for second option how can i define default values? Do i need to do that in Migration file or I need to add that in my datamodel?

Comment: @HardikBhatia Then give your column a Default date value, otherwise you'll have to go through the null records individually and update them.

Comment: I have already modified the table and made sure my PasswordDate column is not null in the database.

Comment: Changing the DB and adding some value to null columns does the trick. I tried that as the first thing but it seems someone else was messing around with DB and inserted a row with the null value in 'PasswordDate' Column.

Comment: In your Up migration add `Sql(@"UPDATE [dbo].[CertificateInfoes] SET [PasswordDate] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE [PasswordDate] IS NULL");` and this will populate data for you. Going back down shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 16):

It's not possible to directly add a non-nullable column to a table that has historical data in the table if no default value is provided for that column.

What I do is

1. add the column as nullable.
2. provide an sql script to populate this newly added column.
3. alter the column to make is as non-nullable.

Code example(with postgres database):

```
 public override void Up()
    {            
        AddColumn("public.YourTableName", "YourColumnName", c => c.Int(nullable: true));
        Sql(@"UPDATE ""public"".""YourTableName""
              SET ""YourColumnName"" = Value you want to set
            ");

        AlterColumn("public.YourTableName", "YourColumnName", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way in EF core 6 would be to alter the migration script where the add column specifies a default value. You can then later drop this default value again.

```cs
public partial class AddOrderSource : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // Add the column with a default value, then drop the default value.
        // This creates a non-nullable column without the migration failing because of existing data.

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "OrderSource",
            table: "Orders",
            type: "int",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 1); // Sample default value

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "OrderSource", 
            table: "Orders",
            oldDefaultValue: 1,
            defaultValue: null
        );
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "OrderSource",
            table: "Orders");
    }
}
```

Comment: Works in EF Core 1.1 as wel.